# Roll 3 dice. Calculate the size of the event where the largest value of d1, d2, d3 is 6.

Tags: probability

The way I approached this is:

Any set of values $ (6,5,x) $ are allowed. So we get $ 6 \times{3} = 18 $

Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong. Cheers.

Comment: If two or three  dice have 6, does that count ?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. But assuming it does, would the answer be 20? It is more the method I'm concerned with.

Comment: "It is more the method I'm concerned with." Then recall the PIE (Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

Calculate the "size of the event" that all three dice show $\leq5$.

Comment: would this be 6^3 - 5^3

Answer (score 0):

Use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion

- Count the ways to select one die to show `6` multiplied by the ways the other dice can show anything.
- Exclude the ways to select two dice to show `6` multiplied by the ways the other die can show anything.
- Include the way all three dice can show `6`.

Can you count the ways?

$$\begin{align}|d_1=6\cup d_2=6\cup d_3=6|
 & = |d_1=6|+|d_2=6|+|d_3=6|
\\ & \ddots -|d_1=6\cap d_2=6|-|d_1=6\cap d_3=6|
\\ & \ddots -|d_2=6\cap d_3=6|+|d_1=6\cap d_2=6\cap d_3=6|\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, use the Law of Complements:

$$\begin{align}|d_1=6\cup d_2=6\cup d_3=6| & = |\mathscr U|-|d_1\neq 6\cap d_2\neq 6 \cap d_3\neq 6|\end{align}$$